# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093] , strange behavour during bulk insert

Tags: php, pdo

Can someone help? I am trying to do a bulk insert (400 rows), everytime it shows an error message after inserted 58 rows in the database, I tried different dataset, it behave the same way.

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Here is the Code:

```
$rows = $_POST['myTableArray'];
$nrecuser= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ndatetime= date('Y-m-d G:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.rec(ncode, nname, nprimary, ndate, nyear, nperiod, 
                            nref, ntype, nuser, ncategorycode1, ncategorycode2, 
                            ncategorycode3, namount, ndescription, naccount, 
                            nmajorheadcode, ncheck, nrecuser, ndatetime) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/db.inc.php';

try
{
  $conn->beginTransaction();

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

  foreach($rows as $row)
  {
    array_push($row, $nrecuser, $ndatetime);
    $stmt->execute($row);

  }

  $conn->commit();
  exit();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{ 
 $conn->rollback();
  echo $e;
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the data you are passing in the array. Maybe row 59 has got something odd about it. Most likely it does not have the correct number of parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out to be a server side issue, all I have to update the php.ini max_input_vars setting. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The number of given insert query parameters is not equal values you are passing to insert

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one line of code (now updated), the $rows has 17 elements + 2 from Array_push, total 19 , I counted it many times. It manage to insert first 58 rows, but failed for the rest.